# Error :- The XmlReader state should be Interactive on XDocument.Load

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I get the following error :-

> System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   XmlReader state should be Interactive.
>   at
>   System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader
>   r, LoadOptions o)     at
>   System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader
>   reader, LoadOptions options)

in the following code. Could anybody point me what I doing wrong here?

```
static XDocument GetContentAsXDocument(string xmlData)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlData))
    {
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlData);
        return xmlDocument.ToXDocument();
    }
    else
    {
        return new XDocument();
    }
}


/// <summary>
///  Converts XMLDocument to XDocument
/// </summary>
/// <param name="xmlDocument"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static XDocument ToXDocument( this XmlDocument xmlDocument )
{
    using( var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader( xmlDocument ) )
    {
        nodeReader.MoveToContent();
        return XDocument.Load(
             nodeReader,
            (LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace |
             LoadOptions.SetBaseUri |
             LoadOptions.SetLineInfo));
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you don't call MoveToContent? I can't test it myself at the moment.

Comment: @Jon, Added that Its needed per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538465.aspx. Will check back and update back.

Comment: @Jon, any reason call to MoveToContent() should not be there? This error is happening for few XMLDocument objects not all.

Comment: @user740431: Yup, found the same thing in the docs. Very strange. I suggest you print out the result of the MoveToContent to call just to check that there really is appropriate data...

Comment: @user7401431: Ah - it would have been nice to know that it wasn't always failing beforehand. In that case you should *definitely* look at the result of MoveToContent, and compare the value in failing and working situations.

Comment: While you are at it you could print nodeReader.ReadState after MoveToContent()
Do you have a sample file that fails, I tried a few documents but it worked for all.

Comment: Just an FYI. I got this error trying to do XElement.ReadFrom() on an XmlReader returned from a stored procedure. Doing MoveToContent() places the reader in 'Interactive' state, and from there ReadFrom() correctly reads the XML.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [XDocument.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx) and [XmlDocument.OuterXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx). See the example below.

```
public static XDocument ToXDocument( this XmlDocument xmlDocument )
{
    string outerXml = xmlDocument.OuterXml;
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(outerXml))
    {
        return XDocument.Parse(outerXml, (LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace |
             LoadOptions.SetBaseUri |
             LoadOptions.SetLineInfo));
    }
    else
    {
        return new XDocument();
    }
}
```

Other methods of [converting from XmlDocument to XDocument can be found here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2009/03/13/fast-way-to-convert-xmldocument-into-xdocument.aspx).